# How to store the choice array_keys as values when using sfWidgetFormChoice when multiple equals true

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Here’s my widget in the Form.Class:

```
$this->widgetSchema['schools'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
    'choices'        => Doctrine_Core::getTable('school')->getUsersSchools($userId),
    'renderer_class' => 'sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList', 
    'renderer_options' => array(
        'label_unassociated' => 'Unassociated',
        'label_associated' => 'Associated'
    )));
```

The above works just fine, but the values that are stored are unassociated to the choices list referenced above.  I need to store the ids of the array retrieved as the values.  Instead, the list that is retrieved is chronological and the ids are ignored.

Here's the schoolTable query:

```
 public function getUsersSchools($id){
          $q =Doctrine_Query::create()
             ->select('id')
             ->from('school')
             ->where('user_id = ?', $id)
             ->execute();
         return $q;
     }
```

Comment: What kind of variable returns `getUsersSchools`? Arrays of ids, collection?

Comment: I believe it's a collection.  I've updated my question to show you the query.

Comment: The form you are using is a generated form and has a `schools` field by default?

Comment: yes, it is a generated form and there is a default field named 'schools'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to store associated school ids.
Use the `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` widget instead and it will work out of the box, as it using primary keys as ids.

```
$query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('school')->queryForSelect($userId);
$this->setWidget('schools', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
  'model' => 'school',
  'query' => $query,
  'multiple' => true,
  'renderer_class' => 'sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList', 
  'renderer_options' => array(
    'label_unassociated' => 'Unassociated',
    'label_associated' => 'Associated'
  ),
)));
$this->setValidator('schools', new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array(
  'model' => 'schoool',
  'query' => $query,
  'multiple' => true,
)));

// in SchoolTable class
public function queryForSelect($userId)
{
  return $this->createQuery('s')
    ->andWhere('s.user_id = ?', $userId)
  ;
}
```

If you has a proper schema (I presume the schools should be a many-to-many association), then the current from should has a `schools_list` field (properly defined in the generated base from) and then you can modify that field to be rendered by `sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList`:

```
$this->widgetSchema['schools_list']->setOption('renderer_class', 'sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList');
$this->widgetSchema['schools_list']->setOption('renderer_options', array(
  'label_unassociated' => 'Unassociated',
  'label_associated' => 'Associated'
));
```